# How can I generate and name 10,000 vectors automatically in R programming?

Tags: r

I have a vector that has 10,000 elements(natural numbers). The vector is, say, End.Num.
I want to generate and name 10,000 new vectors using this vector as below.

```
NewVec1 <- 1:End.Num[1]
NewVec2 <- 1:End.Num[2]
NewVec3 <- 1:End.Num[3]

NewVec9999 <- 1:End.Num[9999]
NewVec10000 <- 1:End.Num[10000]
```

How can I this without writing 10,000 lines in R? Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Any reason why you cannot put these vectors in a `list`?

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

1. Define a function

   ```r
   vec <- function(x) {
     v <- 1:x
   }
   ```
2. Generate a list of vectors

   ```r
   the_list <- lapply(End.Num, FUN = vec)
   ```
3. Split `the_list` in n variables

   ```r
   list2env(setNames(the_list,paste0("v",seq_along(the_list))), envir = parent.frame())
   ```

I advise you to stop at point 2 and to access the elements of the list via `the_list[[i]]`.